# Extract the code inside the map(...) call

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I would like to extract the code inside the `map(...)` method in the example code into separate line (the code is too long now, affecting readability):

```
final Specification<PeriodicInvoice> noFilterClause = Specification.where(null);
Optional<Date> of = ...;

of.map(f -> Specification.<PeriodicInvoice> where((root, query, cb) -> cb.greaterThan(root.<Date> get("fromPeriod"), f)))
            .orElse(noFilterClause);
```

I do not wish to write a new function. I would like to inline the extracted code one line above the `of.map(...)`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store that lambda expression in a variable of `Function` type:

```
final Specification<PeriodicInvoice> noFilterClause = Specification.where(null);
Optional<Date> of = ...;

Function<Date,Specification<PeriodicInvoice>> mapper = 
    f -> Specification.<PeriodicInvoice> where((root, query, cb) -> cb.greaterThan(root.<Date> get("fromPeriod"), f));
of.map(mapper)
  .orElse(noFilterClause);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried exactly that at least thousand times but did always run into a bloody 'Target type must be function expression'. But hey with your answer it works. I probably mismanaged the `Function` import before. Thank you!